# Autocompletion in a nested form text field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using rails 5 and i want to autocomplete a text field which is in a nested form. The nested form has been generated via cocoon. 
When i try to use auto complete function in the parent form it works fine. However it seems like my javascript doesnt work for the nested form.

This is model file of the nested form

```
class Programline < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :program, inverse_of: :programlines
belongs_to :exercise


def exercise_name
 exercise.try(:exe_desc)
end

def exercise_name=(exe_desc)
 self.exercise = Exercise.find_by_exe_desc(exe_desc) if 
 exe_desc.present?
end



end
```

This is my text field within the nested form.

```
 <%= f.text_field :exercise_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Exercise.order(:exe_desc).map(&:exe_desc)} ,class: "form-control", placeholder: "Exercise", autofocus: true %>
```

This is my javascript file.

```
     jQuery
     $(function() {
      $(document).on("focus","programline_exercise_name", function() {
        $('programline_exercise_name').autocomplete({
            source: $('programline_exercise_name').data('autocomplete- source')
              }); 
                });
                  })
```

When i fill the form it works fine, inserts data and builds relationship without any problem. But it does not automatically find the data which is in exercise table.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: you have `$('programline_exercise_name')`, `programline_exercise_name` should be `#programline_exercise_name` . **JQuery selector can work on HTML tags or tag attributes such as id, class, etc.**

Comment: @dp7, thanks for the heads up but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cross-posted this in [cocoon issues](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/502), so I will replicate my answer to you here.

Your selection filter for jquery seems wrong. You write `on("focus","programline_exercise_name"` and `$('programline_exercise_name')` which would go looking for a html-element with that name. Like `$('p')` will select all paragraphs. I am assuming you want to select an element with id or class `programline_exercise_name` ? For dynamically added fields you would definitely be using a class, but then your jquery snippet would also be wrong.

So if you add the wanted class-name to the field

```
<%= f.text_field :exercise_name, data: { autocomplete_source: Exercise.order(:exe_desc).map(&:exe_desc)},
      class: "form-control programline_exercise_name", 
      placeholder: "Exercise", 
      autofocus: true %>
```

You would then need something like

```
$(document).on("focus", ".programline_exercise_name", function() {
  var _this = $(this); 
  _this.autocomplete({
    source: _this.data('autocomplete- source')
  }); 
});
```

Not tested, so let me explain: when the focus event is triggered on any of the text-fields with class `.programline_exercise_name`, only set the autocomplete for the element that caused the event.

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery should look as follows (assuming your nested field has id `programline_exercise_name`) :

```
$(function() {
 $(document).on("focus","#programline_exercise_name", function() {
   $('#programline_exercise_name').autocomplete({
       source: $('#programline_exercise_name').data('autocomplete- source')
    }); 
 });
});
```

Comment: @SonKurc You have to debug whether your jquery event is working or not.